# Stored procedure not found after apparently successful migration in Flyway

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, database-migration, flyway

I'm using flyway and have a bunch of oracle stored procedures in a sql script. The sql script status shows success during flyway migration but some of the stored procedures are not found in the database. After removing a particular stored procedure and keeping it a next version during migration, the stored procedures are found for strange reason. Not sure how this one is messing up others as I don't see any error.

```
 Version |  State  |                  Source                 |          Date Installed         |
+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|       1 | SUCCESS |                             V1__DDL.sql | Mon, 16 Jun 2014 10:55:30 -0400
```

Comment: Are you sure your checks/queries and the Flyway migration are addressing the same database and schema?

Comment: I haven't used flyway before, but is it possible a subsequent version of the script was applied that did not have this procedure?

Comment: If I keep a particular misbehaving stored procedure at the end of the script, all other procedures are found. I'm unsure if that is messing up others.

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue including steps to reproduce, client & db versions. Also ensure you have run this with the latest Flyway version (currently 3.0).